Error when connecting a database from node.js
So I have this error, I made my database in phpMyAdmin and I am trying to connect the database, but I can't. I am new to website development so I am unsure what I am doing. Any help is more than welcome.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Thanks
Error connecting: AggregateError at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18) at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5) -------------------- at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\Vanja\Desktop\Book-Swap\backEnd\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48) at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\Vanja\Desktop\Book-Swap\backEnd\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23) at Connection.connect (C:\Users\Vanja\Desktop\Book-Swap\backEnd\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Vanja\Desktop\Book-Swap\backEnd\test.js:11:4) at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14) at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10) at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32) at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12) at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49
This is the code I have, it's a simple test script to just check if the connecting of the database is working, I tried troubleshooting it myself but I got nowhere. I am attaching a picture to show that the sisiii_project database does exist.
https://i.sstatic.net/9nYEnfGK.png
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    port: 8081,
    password: '',
    database: 'sisiii_project'
});

db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected as id ' + db.threadId);
    db.end(); // Close the connection immediately for this test
});


Did you try using the newer mysql2 module to connect to mysql instead of the old mysql module?

From the screenshot you shared, your port seems to be 4306 but then you are using 8081 in your config.  I think you should check your database credentials

Using mysql2 fixed the issue for me. The port was 4306 but that didn't work so I wanted to try every single think I could.
